# Why doesn't the left column come down in ms word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-word, column, page

[image]

I want the left column to be full.
Why does the left column not come down? Any Suggestions?

Comment: Remove the spaces.

Comment: Removing space doesn't do anything.

Comment: Instead of the regular line return (Enter), have you tried Shift+Return?

Comment: I don't know much about other page layout of your document. If possible, it is recommended to backup the document and delete the last section break (continue) to have a check.

Comment: Do you want the left column not to have blank lines? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

### The continuous section break at the end tells Word to start a single column section at that point.

This causes the columns to wrap and balance. If you type more in the first column they will both grow.

You could change the following section to the same two columns and then delete the continuous section mark.

If you want to prevent such wrapping / balancing, you would want to create the column without selecting text and have it set for from this point forward.

[image: screenshot]